# awk linux shell seems error

Tags: shell, awk

I am not a master in the linux shell commands and I have a little prob to understand what is wrong in my commands :

when I run this

```
netstat -lptn | cut -d : -f 2,3,4,5,6,7
```

the result is  ;

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Adresse locale          Adresse distante        Etat       PID/Program name
631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      853/cupsd       
445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      803/smbd        
139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      803/smbd        
53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1394/dnsmasq    
:1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      853/cupsd       
::445                  :::*                    LISTEN      803/smbd        
::139                  :::*                    LISTEN      803/smbd
```

Ok now I add extra command the 'awk' to filter the result like that :

```
netstat -lptn | cut -d : -f 2,3,4,5,6,7 |awk 'BEGIN {res="Down"} /^445.*smbd$/ {res=$3} END {print res}
```

But the  result  shows `down` inspite the second line meets the pattern :

```
445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      803/smbd
```

so why i could not have the good result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
/^445.*smbd$/
```

but take a look the 2nd line, there are trailing spaces/tabs after `smbd`. so it won't be matched.

try this:

```
.......|awk 'BEGIN {res="Down"} /^445.*smbd\s*$/ {res=$3} END {print res}'
```

with your example data as input, the above awk print

```
LISTEN
```